# RabbitMQ Message Deduplication

Tags: duplicates, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am looking for a deduplication mechanic with RabbitMQ. I tried the [`rabbitmq-message-deduplication`](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication), but it does only consider messages that are not delivered yet. I need to go one step further and also cache a certain amount of already delivered (and acknowledged) messages and also refer to these messages when considering an incoming message a duplicate. Is there any way to implement this with RabbitMQ or should I simply consider another service? My problem is that, for reasons of redundancy, I have several producers that send the same message, but they can be several minutes apart. So I need to avoid processing a message by a consumer that has already been processed before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the [`rabbitmq-message-deduplication`](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) on an exchange in front of a queue to get the desired results. Applying the plugin directly to a queue leads to the undesired state that is described in the initial post.